# Problem with graph

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, computability, np-complete

We have the following graph: 
[image]

I want to find a minimal vertex cover. 
I thought that the set $C^\star=\{1,2,3,7\}$ is a minimal vertx cover. Is this correct? How could we prove it?

$$$$

Then I want to find a vertex cover using the following approximation algorithm

```
C <- 0 
while E ≠ 0 do 
    choose e = (u,v) ∈ E arbitrary 
    C <- C U {u,v} 
    G <- G - {u,v} 
return C
```

I have done the following: 
Suppose we start with e=(1,4) then C={1,4} and the graph is the following: 
[image] 
Then when we choose e=(5,7) we have C={1,4,5,7} and the graph will look as follows: 
[image] 
Then we can choose e=(2,3) and then we have C={1,2,3,4,5,7} and the graph will be: 
[image] 
Have we finished now? 
Is a minimal vertex cover the set $C=\{1,2,3,4,5,7\}$ ?

Does this mean that no matter which edge we choose at each step the minimal vertex cover will contain $6$ vertices?

$$$$

After that I want to find a maximal independent set of vertices and a maximal clique. Could you give me some hints how we could find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that the set $C^⋆=\{1,2,3,7\}$ is a minimal vertex cover. Is this correct? How could we prove it?

No, because it does not cover all edges (in particular, none of the edges $\{4, 5\}, \{5, 6\}, \{4, 6\}$ are covered by any vertex in $C^*$).

> Have we finished now? Is a minimal vertex cover the set $C=\{1,2,3,4,5,7\}$? Does this mean that no matter which edge we choose at each step the minimal vertex cover will contain $6$ vertices?

Yes, you've correctly implemented the greedy $2$-approximation algorithm. It is not minimal though: observe that $C$ has a subset $\{1, 3, 4, 5, 7\}$, which is still a vertex cover. So this greedy algorithm is not guaranteed to be optimal.

> After that I want to find a maximal independent set of vertices and a maximal clique. Could you give me some hints how we could find them?

As a general heuristic, try a modified greedy algorithm. When picking vertices, don't just pick any random one; try picking the one with the lowest (or highest) degree. Then remove it (and anything else that we know is safe to remove) from the graph and repeat.

Comment: So, is a minimal vertex cover the set $C^\star=\{1,3,4,5,7\}$ ? $$$$ For the maximal independent set of vertices, is it maybe $\{1,5,6\}$ ? $$$$ Is maybe the following a maximal clique? $\{1,2,3,4\}$ ?

Comment: Yes. No, since $\{5, 6\}$ is an edge in the graph. No, since $\{3, 4\}$ is not an edge in the graph.

Comment: Could we prove that $C^\star$ is a minimal vertex cover? So, is a maximal independent set of vertices the set $\{1,5\}$ ? Is a maximal clique the set $\{4,5,6,7\}$ ?

Comment: Just show that if you try to remove any single vertex from $C^*$, some edge doesn't get covered. Yes, $\{1, 5\}$ is a maximal independent set (in fact, it's also maximum). Yes, $\{4, 5, 6, 7\}$ is a maximal clique (in fact, it's also maximum).

Comment: Ah ok!! After that I want to compute the chromatic number of $G$. I did the following: [http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4445/j8gpiofd_png.htm], so the chromatic number would be $3$. Is this correct? $$$$ Also I want to check if the graph has an eulerian cycle and a hamiltonian cycle. At the eulerian cycle we want to start and at the same vertex and pass from each edge just once. So, is an eulerian cycle the following? $(1,2,3,6,5,7,4,1)$ ? Is this also a hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: You used $4$ colours, so the chromatic number is at most $4$ (can you see why the chromatic number could never be $3$?). You provided a Hamiltonian cycle, but not an Eulerian circuit (for example, you did not visit the edges $\{1, 3\}$,  $\{2, 5\}$, and so on).

Comment: Oh yes... So, the chromatic number of $G$ is $4$. Ah ok... Does the graph has no Eulerian circuit because there are node with odd degree?

Comment: That's correct.